# How can I fix roller marks on a surface with oblique lighting?

Tags: painting

I am painting a stairway with a ceiling light shining down at the top of the stairs. The walls have been textured with mud and a loop roller. At the bottom of the steps there are windows and a glass door that reflect light on the upper section of the stairs. I used 2 coats of primer and also 2 coats of BM regal paint and a Wooster lambswool roller cover. The problem is that when looking upwards from the bottom of the stairs, I can see uneven places that look like roller marks. The landing and flat walls look perfect. I put a straight edge on the problem areas and they are straight. Is this the way stairwells are because of light reflection or is there something I can do? The paint color is a very light gray and the ceiling light has fairly dim bulbs.

Comment: Is your problem with the texture or the paint?

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Still unclear of what is the problem you dislike of the texture or the paint?

Comment: If the wall is textured I can't imagine there would be paint streaks. How pronounced is the texture? There are paint sprayers, and I think one of them being used could resolve your issue, as opposed to rolling the paint.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a shadow line?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble with lighting I would suggest covering the window and door and putting a work light somewhere on the stairwell close to the wall so you can make sure your lighting is even and you don’t miss any spots. I have problems with lighting sometimes and that always seems to help me especially on textured walls.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem now.  (Saw the same thing with light gray over orange peel with a 1/2" roller cover )

The 1/2" nap is too heavy for a texture like orange peel.  I have seen the lines from the edge of the roller cover get pronounced at certain angles.

Roll another coat with a 3/"8 " cover.. you may be able to just roll the areas that have the noticeable lines.